# Retrieve variable name stored in MySQL and echo the value?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a yql url for a script.  I have made parts of the url variables and then just reconstructed them together.  This is just in case anything changes then I can make an easy fix.

$cllrssformat gets the rss feeds that are in the yql url. I have replaced the search term with the variable $clsearch and stored that in mysql table.  I was expecting that it would write the value of $clsearch, but it only shows $clsearch (literally).

This is an example of what I have stored in the mysql table.

```
'http://daytona".$clsearch."','http://keys".$clsearch."'
```

And this is the PHP code.

```
// link to yql
$yqlurl = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';
// yql query
$yqlquery = 'select title,source,description,date from rss where url in ( ';
// cl search parameters
$clsearch = '.somesite.com/search/sss?query=blah+blah&srchType=T&minAsk=&maxAsk=&format=rss';
// yql sort paramaters
$yqlparams = ' ) | unique(field="source") | sort(field="date", descending="true")';
//  cl rss feeds formatted for yql
$clrssformat = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM be_yqlurls WHERE id='1'");
$temp = mysql_fetch_row($clrssformat);
$clrssformat = $temp[0];
// create the full url
$fullurl= $yqlurl.$yqlquery.$clrssformat.$yqlparams;
$fullurl = rawurlencode($fullurl);
echo rawurldecode($fullurl)
// echo '<br><br>'.$fullurl;
```

This is the output.  Obviously needing the value of $clsearch vs. "$clsearch".

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select title,source,description,date from rss where url in ( 'http://daytona".$clsearch."','http://keys".$clsearch."','http://fortlauderdale".$clsearch."','http://fortmyers".$clsearch."','http://gainesville".$clsearch."','http://cfl".$clsearch."' ) | unique(field="source") | sort(field="date", descending="true")
```

First real try with PHP so be easy.  :)  Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Do you want to have $clsearch that you pull from the database replaces with $clsearch that you have in the PHP variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly I *think* that what you need to do is:

```
// create the full url
$fullurl= str_replace('$clsearch', $clsearch, $yqlurl.$yqlquery.$clrssformat.$yqlparams);
```

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks.  Love this site.